# Optimizing Multiple SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 queries that I want to optimize but I don't know how. The execution time is not acceptable for me.

I'm working with jira database and did query to show different tasks with some attributes.
The code is:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TT
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TT1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TT2

SELECT DISTINCT concat(pr.[pkey], '-', ji.[issuenum]) AS 'Ключ'
        ,concat('https://sd.finam.ru/browse/', pr.[pkey], '-', ji.[issuenum]) AS 'Ссылка'
        ,p.[pname] AS 'П'
        ,users.[display_name] AS 'Исполнитель'
        ,CAST(ji.[CREATED] AS smalldatetime) AS 'Создан'
        ,CAST(ji.[RESOLUTIONDATE] AS smalldatetime) AS 'Дата резолюции'
        ,ji.[issuenum]
INTO #TT
  FROM
    [jiraissue] AS ji
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [changegroup] AS cg ON (cg.[issueid] = ji.[id])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [changeitem] AS ci ON (ci.[groupid] = cg.[id]) AND ci.FIELDTYPE='jira' AND ci.FIELD='status'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [app_user] AS au ON (au.[user_key] = cg.[AUTHOR])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [issuetype] AS itype ON (itype.[ID] = ji.[issuetype])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [priority] AS p ON (p.[ID] = ji.[PRIORITY])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [project] AS pr ON (pr.[ID] = ji.[PROJECT])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [cwd_user] as users ON (users.[user_name] = ji.[ASSIGNEE])
      
  WHERE cg.[CREATED] >= CONVERT(datetime, '2021-12-01') AND cg.[CREATED] <= CONVERT(datetime, '2022-01-01') and CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ci.[NEWSTRING]) = N'Done'
  AND itype.pname = 'Incident'

SELECT DISTINCT concat(pr.[pkey], '-', ji.[issuenum]) AS 'Ключ'
        ,system_t.[NAME] AS 'Контур ИС'
        ,system_t_t.[NAME] AS 'Критичность системы'
INTO #TT1
  FROM
    [jiraissue] AS ji
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [changegroup] AS cg ON (cg.[issueid] = ji.[id])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [changeitem] AS ci ON (ci.[groupid] = cg.[id]) AND ci.FIELDTYPE='jira' AND ci.FIELD='status'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [app_user] AS au ON (au.[user_key] = cg.[AUTHOR])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [issuetype] AS itype ON (itype.[ID] = ji.[issuetype])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [project] AS pr ON (pr.[ID] = ji.[PROJECT])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [customfieldvalue] AS customfv ON (customfv.[ISSUE] = ji.[ID])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [AO_8542F1_IFJ_OBJ] AS system_t ON (system_t.[ID] = substring(customfv.[STRINGVALUE], PatIndex('%[0-9]%', customfv.[STRINGVALUE]), len(customfv.[STRINGVALUE])))
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [AO_8542F1_IFJ_OBJ_ATTR] AS system_attr ON (system_t.[ID] = system_attr.[OBJECT_ID])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [AO_8542F1_IFJ_OBJ_ATTR_VAL] AS system_attr_val ON (system_attr.[ID] = system_attr_val.[OBJECT_ATTRIBUTE_ID])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [AO_8542F1_IFJ_OBJ] AS system_t_t ON (system_attr_val.[REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID] = system_t_t.[ID])
      
  WHERE cg.[CREATED] >= CONVERT(datetime, '2021-12-01') AND cg.[CREATED] <= CONVERT(datetime, '2022-01-01') and CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ci.[NEWSTRING]) = N'Done'
  AND (customfv.[CUSTOMFIELD] = 21003 OR customfv.[CUSTOMFIELD] = 21005)
  AND (system_t.[OBJECT_TYPE_ID] = 136 OR system_t.[OBJECT_TYPE_ID] = 303 OR system_t.[OBJECT_TYPE_ID] = 143)
  AND system_attr.[OBJECT_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE_ID] = 461
  AND itype.pname = 'Incident'

SELECT ji.[issuenum]
    ,pr_pr.[pname] AS '(project) Project'

INTO #TT2
  FROM
    [jiraissue] AS ji
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [customfieldvalue] AS customfv ON (customfv.[ISSUE] = ji.[ID])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [project] AS pr_pr ON (pr_pr.[ID] = CAST(customfv.[NUMBERVALUE] AS BIGINT))
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [changegroup] AS cg ON (cg.[issueid] = ji.[id])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [changeitem] AS ci ON (ci.[groupid] = cg.[id]) AND ci.FIELDTYPE='jira' AND ci.FIELD='status'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [app_user] AS au ON (au.[user_key] = cg.[AUTHOR])
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [issuetype] AS itype ON (itype.[ID] = ji.[issuetype])
  WHERE cg.[CREATED] >= CONVERT(datetime, '2021-12-01') AND cg.[CREATED] <= CONVERT(datetime, '2022-01-01') and CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ci.[NEWSTRING]) = N'Done'
  AND pr_pr.[pname] is not NULL

  SELECT CTE.[Ключ], CTE.[Ссылка], CTE.[П], CTE.[Исполнитель], CTE.[Создан], CTE.[Дата резолюции], CTE2.[(project) Project], CTE1.[Контур ИС], CTE1.[Критичность системы], CTE.[issuenum]
  FROM #TT CTE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #TT1 CTE1 ON (CTE1.[Ключ] = CTE.[Ключ])
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #TT2 CTE2 ON (CTE2.[issuenum] = CTE.[issuenum])

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TT
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TT1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TT2
```

There will be some information for the month before last.

[summary of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlgNJ.png)

The next query is:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT concat(p.pkey,'-',i.issuenum) AS 'Ключ', 
       cf.cfname, 
       cv.textvalue,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.issuenum ORDER BY i.issuenum) AS RowNumber_SLA 
FROM   customfield cf, 
       customfieldvalue cv, 
       jiraissue i, 
       project p 
WHERE  i.project = p.id 
       AND cv.issue = i.id 
       AND cv.customfield = cf.id 
       AND cf.customfieldtypekey = 'com.atlassian.servicedesk:sd-sla-field'
       and i.issuenum IN ()
       and CHARINDEX('"succeeded":false', TEXTVALUE) >0
)

SELECT CTE.Ключ
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNumber_SLA = 1
```

The goal is to get tasks where SLA has been failed.
So in `and i.issuenum IN ()` my Python script is putting issue numbers that I got through previous query.
The average execution time is 3 minutes.
So, I want optimize this too, maybe join first query.
Sorry for my English. I'm not an English-speaking person.

P. S. Changing `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ci.[NEWSTRING]) = N'Done'` to `ci.[NEWSTRING] = 'Done'` causing the error `The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.` Workaround - `ci.[NEWSTRING] LIKE 'Done'` fixing this.

Comment: Which database system are you using the used syntax suggests SQL server

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Tip - you can use `drop table if exists t1, t2, t3...`

Comment: It seems you are also unsure what `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is for. In your first batch, for example, you `LEFT JOIN` to `[changegroup]`, `[changeitem]` and `[issuetype]`, however, you state in the `WHERE` that columns from those tables but *not* be `NULL`, meaning that the `JOIN`s to `[changegroup]`, `[changegroup]` and `[issuetype]` are all implicit `INNER JOIN`s instead. As such, why are you using a `LEFT JOIN` when you require a row to be returned? Also why are you converting `ci.[NEWSTRING]` to an `nvarchar(MAX)` in your `WHERE`? That will be terrrible for performance.

Comment: Yes, guess that I should replace JOINs; converting is done because of error `The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.`

Comment: My experience shows me that beginner developers sometimes systematically use the LEFT OUTER JOIN whatever the join is because they have not understood nor studied the principle of joins... This is not very serious in this case because SQL Sever rectifies false OUTER to INNER on the fly as soon as a WHERE clause specifies an outer table... But this is a stupid attitude that can lead to the return of false data!

Comment: The fact that you are using a data type (`ntext`) that has been deprecated for *17 years* and the error should have been included in your question, @luibrain . You should be fixing your design and not be using said data type. Use the "new" (I wouldn't say 17 years old is new mind) `MAX` length data types if you *must* have values that need to be up to 2GB in size.

Answer (score 1):

The first query must be rewrite as :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       concat(pr.[pkey], '-', ji.[issuenum]) AS 'Ключ', 
       concat('https://sd.finam.ru/browse/', pr.[pkey], '-', ji.[issuenum]) AS 'Ссылка', 
       p.[pname] AS 'П', 
       users.[display_name] AS 'Исполнитель', 
       CAST(ji.[CREATED] AS SMALLDATETIME) AS 'Создан', 
       CAST(ji.[RESOLUTIONDATE] AS SMALLDATETIME) AS 'Дата резолюции', 
       ji.[issuenum]
INTO #TT
FROM [jiraissue] AS ji
     INNER JOIN [changegroup] AS cg ON(cg.[issueid] = ji.[id])
     INNER JOIN [changeitem] AS ci ON(ci.[groupid] = cg.[id])
                                          AND ci.FIELDTYPE = 'jira'
                                          AND ci.FIELD = 'status'
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [app_user] AS au ON(au.[user_key] = cg.[AUTHOR])
     INNER JOIN [issuetype] AS itype ON(itype.[ID] = ji.[issuetype])
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [priority] AS p ON(p.[ID] = ji.[PRIORITY])
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [project] AS pr ON(pr.[ID] = ji.[PROJECT])
     LEFT OUTER JOIN [cwd_user] AS users ON(users.[user_name] = ji.[ASSIGNEE])
WHERE cg.[CREATED] >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-12-01')
      AND cg.[CREATED] <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2022-01-01')
      AND ci.[NEWSTRING] = 'Done'
      AND itype.pname = 'Incident';
```

False outer joins are converted in INNER and I have aslo eliminate the ugly CONVERT to NVARCHAR(max)

Same troubles appears in the second query...

Comment: Thank you a lot! OUTER to INNER didn't give me so much but eliminating converting is a very good solution, but still `ci.[NEWSTRING] = 'Done'` not working, changed to `ci.[NEWSTRING] LIKE 'Done'` and its' ok. What about SLA part? How can I attach this to the first query?

Comment: `ci.[NEWSTRING] = 'Done'` and `ci.[NEWSTRING] LIKE 'Done'` are synonyms, @luibrain, as the expression on the right hand side contains no wildcards. If `= 'Done'` "doesn't work" (what ever that means) then neither will `LIKE 'Done'`.

Comment: @Larnu, so then it's the magic :D Got error `The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.` when `ci.[NEWSTRING] = 'Done'` but query works when `ci.[NEWSTRING] LIKE 'Done'`

Comment: it's not "magic" @luibrain , the problem is you are using a data type (`ntext`) that has been deprecated for **17 years**. You should be fixing your design to be using the `MAX` length data types.

Comment: @Luibrain you must ask yourself why you need ci.[NEWSTRING] LIKE 'Done' ? which is a bad equivalent to =... Perhaps some blank chars ? ...

Comment: @SQLpro it is for work purposes, I need to get tasks which their status changed to 'Done'